# Mobile Application Revese Gateway recomendation

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, mdm

I have a mobile application that communicates with a REST based web-service.  The web-service lives behind the firewall and talks to other systems. Currently this web-service requires a firewall port to be opened and a SSL cert generated for each installation. Mobile apps sends login credentials so web-services can login to custom back-end systems.

Recently a customer approached us asking how could we deploy this to 50 offices.  As we don't want to say modify every firewall in every office, we're looking for options..  This is a list of possible solutions and my thoughts on each one:

1. Open firewall port and expose https webservice - This is our current
   solution but we dont want to have to contact 50 network admins and explain why we need to do this.
2. VPN - Too heavy weight, complex and expensive, we only need access
   to one server. Does not solve problem as firewall needs to be
       modified.
3. Microsoft Azure Hybrid Connection Manager - This provides a managed
           service where the Azure cloud will expose an end point.  Azure will
           also expect connections from a easy to install application that
           lives behind the firewall.  When a REST call is made to the cloud
           end-point, the request is forward down socket that was initiated by
           the software behind the firewall. This does what we want but as its
           a Microsoft Solution there might impose other requirements that our
           customers might not want. Currently the simple Hybrid Connection Manager is free.  But for how long?
4. Jscape MFT Gateway - Similar to Azure but you can host their server        anywhere.  Not that expensive but is not opensource.
5. Netty - A async java library/toolkit where this type of application could easily be build.  Client and server apps would need to be build and deployed. Dont know what we dont know about Netty.
6. MDM, AirWatch, BlackBerry BES - A MDM based solution would work expect that MDM's are centrally managed and are not often in every office where the backend services are located. Airwatch has an AppTunnle but im not sure about the specifics.

At this point the Microsoft and Jscape systems are possible solutions.

But most likely these solutions will require us to modify the mobile software to work around issues such as:

- How does the user know which server to login to?  A locator service
  needs to be built such that, an email address is used to lookup their
  office, or they need to select their office location from a list.
- While the connection is SSL many company might want some additional protection since network login information will be send down the pipe.
- How is load balancing and fail-over managed?

So, at this point i'm looking for more options.  The best option would be a commercial product that offers some level of customization.  Second, would like a well used open-source product that could be installed in Aws and customized.

Thanks

Comment: FYI,  GoAnywhere has the best solution [link] http://www.goanywheremft.com/

Comment: Found a node.js module called node-reverse-wstunnel.  It works but has a several issues to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach we found was to use the PUTTY API and setup a reverse proxy.